# NodeMCU what is my esp3286 core version

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu

How do I find out what my esp3286 core version using Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools Menu -> Board -> Boards Manager - scroll down to the core and see what version it is.